# Using python-docx's _document method

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I am using python-docx and am trying to insert the a `<w:bookmarkStart>` tag. I do not see any immediate API method to create the tag. So I googled several references to gain access to the raw XML using the `document._document_part` attribute. However, when I attempt to use it, python tells me it does not exist:

```
>>> import docx
>>> document = docx.Document()
>>> print document._document_part
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute '_document_part'
```

I am using python-docx 0.8.5.

Is there a method to add a `<w:bookmarkStart>` tag?

Comment: Names with a leading underscore are *"private-by-convention"*, so you should not rely on them for functionality; the developer may have changed the class's internal implementation, removing that attribute entirely.

Comment: If that is a private by convention method, is there a way to add in arbitrary XML tags? I still need to add this `<w:bookmarkStart>` tag...

Comment: After reading the python-docx source, it seems that you can utilize `document._part`. However, I am still not certain how to use it...

Comment: Again, you should not be relying on internal implementation for your functionality. Bookmarks are not currently supported, by the looks of things, though there's an open issue to do so: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/171

Comment: I found the solution. Here's an example:
`from docx.oxml.shared import OxmlElement # Necessary Import` \
`tags = document.element.xpath('//w:r') # Locate the right <w:r> tag` \
`tag = tags[0] # Specify which <w:r> tag you want` \
`child = OxmlElement('w:ARBITRARY') # Create arbitrary tag` \
`tag.append(child) # Append in the new tag` \
To add an attribute:
`from docx.oxml.shared import qn` \
`child.set( qn('w:val'), 'VALUE') # Add in the value` \

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Here's an example:

```
from docx.oxml.shared import OxmlElement # Necessary Import

tags = document.element.xpath('//w:r') # Locate the right <w:r> tag

tag = tags[0] # Specify which <w:r> tag you want

child = OxmlElement('w:ARBITRARY') # Create arbitrary tag

tag.append(child) # Append in the new tag
```

To add an attribute:

```
from docx.oxml.shared import qn

child.set( qn('w:val'), 'VALUE') # Add in the value
```